# How to I replace "\\" instead of "\" in java or Jquery

Tags: java

I have a path like "C:java\test\some.txt". I want to replace "\\" instead of "\" in that string.

help me to resolve the problem

Comment: What do you plan to do with the result?  If you have a `String` and the value of the `String` already contains \ characters, it's not common that you'd need to replace them with \\.  Please be clear on what you're trying to accomplish, so that we can help figure out if you really want to do the replacement you say you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, 
stringVariable.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) 92) , "\\");

Comment: Does this work?  It looks like you're replacing a backslash with a backslash, which means you're doing nothing.  If you want the second parameter to be a string with two backslashes, you need _four_ backslashes in your code.

Comment: Actually single backslash throws compilation error. if i change it as double slash then it works fine.